# What does 「そうもいかなくて」 mean in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

This comes from 新完全マスター読解N2:

> でも、現実にはなかなか**そうもいかなくて**、目の前にあるのは希望とはまったく違うものだけれども、転職するのも大変だから、いやいや会社に通っているという人も多いでしょう。

Seems like it may mean something like "it's not like that"?

What are the words/particles at work here? そう+も+いかない?

Comment: The phrase seems to be referring to what was said before.  This sentence starts of something along the lines of "In reality, it doesn't really come out that way..."  So, you're not that far off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That means, ”(I have an ideal, a plan or a hope etc. but) the reality is defferent and it doesn't go well as much as I expect."

So, this phrase imply that the speaker has an expectation for anything but actually it hasn't meet to his/her expectation yet.

You can also say in other words, "そう＋は＋いかない/いかなくて”, "うまく+いかなくて".

In this context, above both phrases are same.